# Internet Connection Problems over Cellular

Tags: android

We have discovered a strange bug in on of our Android apps in that the app cannot connect to the internet over cellular on certain Android Models/Mobile Networks (connecting via WiFi works perfectly). The URL which the app is trying is to reach is however accessible using the device's normal browser, which rules out the URL being blocked upstream. Any ideas what could be causing this would be appreciated please.

Comment: incorrect APN setting , weak signal , maintenance in progress by your cellular network provider ...

Comment: @ShivanRaptor The phone we are testing has full 3G and there is no problem accessing the internet in general using the browser...

Comment: maybe the hosts file contains invalid records . It's at `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor do you mean the hosts file on the device or in the apk?

Comment: on the device. Try to locate it in your problematic devices

Comment: Which models/networks (Android versions)?  Maybe it could be a relevant information. Additionaly, what does the Logcat show when you are trying to connect to the _problematic URL_?

Comment: @FedericoCristina It is affecting a variety of devices, but I can say with certainty the Samsung S3 and Motorola Droid RAZR. The Samsung is running Android 4.0.4, the Droid's version is unknown.

Comment: Could be anything, you don't say how you connect to the URL from your app.

Comment: I once had a home video camera accessible for management over the internet. Worked fine on Verizon (Android) but not ATT (iPhone). Turned out that ATT was blocking the ActiveX control in the management web page. I was surprised to hear this and surprised I actually got a confirmation from ATT. I have also seen Verizon drop my connection if I use certain protocols, commands.  The point is maybe the carrier blocks by query string or other thing. Can't hurt to call them.

Comment: What exception are you getting when connecting through cellular network?

Comment: Arun - This was a few years ago, basically the active X control would not load in the iPad, I do not think it threw up an error.  I never debugged it on the iPad either.  A year or two before that I had tried to attach to a Windows share (command line if I remember right) with two devices I owned.  When I did so Verizon dropped my connection each time instantly. No errors reported by the carrier that I was aware of.

Answer (score 2):

> which rules out the URL being blocked upstream

Not necessarily. As one of the commenters pointed out, you do not indicate how you are using this URL in your app. If this is an HTTP request, and it works in a browser but not your app, try changing the `User-Agent` HTTP header of your request to match the one from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You have provided no error log, but from experience I have run into a few inconsistencies when connecting to a server.

Using `HttpsUrlConnection` a SNI header is set on HoneyComb and above but not on previous versions, which can alter how the server responds. To add to this there are some general SSL handling inconsistencies between API levels, such as handling of wildcard domains in a certificate is buggy in some api levels.

Second some phones/api levels add a header to `HttpUrlConnection` requests that specifies time the request was sent like so:

```
X-Android-Sent-Millis=1353085024868
```

Some servers seem to use these headers to detect mobile traffic and alter the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems when using a dual-simcard. Do you have more devices connected? Try to shut them down.